# How to call a method in dropdown?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to call  graph based on selected drop down value, the method is graph($p), in that I will pass parameter based on $p graph will change.How to call that method inside option tag.

```
<?php
//connect  database
include("C:\wamp64\www\DashBoard\Config2.php");
$pro_name=array();

        $sql = "select project_name from project_table";
        $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

        $pro="select  count(project_name)from project_table;";
        $res=mysqli_query($db,$pro);
        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($res);
        $cntp=$row['count(project_name)'];

   echo "<select name='project_name'>";
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        $pro_name[]=$row['project_name'];

        }
  for($p=0;$p<$cntp;$p++){

      echo '<option >'.$pro_name[$p].'</option>';

   }             


echo "</select>";
?>
```

Can Any one help me. and the written graph method is php method.

Comment: If the method is global method then you can directly call within the dropdown.

I highly suggest you to pass the parameters once you click on the dropdown link.

Comment: PHP is a server-side language, which means you cannot call its functions like javascript functions. In order for PHP to process new data, you're going to have to post data to the page using HTML form or URL encoded as @ChannaveerHakari mentioned. Which I see partial. Another approach is AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Once you click the drop down link you can pass the parameters in the URL to the subsequent pages as GET parameter and can access the parameters over there and do the modifications.

The following snippet shows you one of the ways to achieve it.

NOTE : There are other ways to achieve. But I am showing you the easiest one. Please make sure to check for the securities best pracites as I wont incorporate here.

in HTML

```
echo '<option > <a  href="link.php?par1=$par1&par2=$par2">'.$pro_name[$p].'</option>';
```

In **link.php** file.

```
<?php 

    $par1 = $_GET['par1'];

    $par2 = $_GET['par2'];

    /* Your code */
```

**Second way**

```
echo '<option>'. someFunction($par1, $par2) .'</option>';
```

Comment: Sir, I am not getting this one.

Comment: What would you like to know. Can you please elobrate, so that I can help you better

Comment: '.$pro_name[$p].' this will print  some text. I need to give click action to that.When we click on that it has to call graph($p) function with passing parameter. The graph($p) function is php function. How to do this.